# Installation of Riak under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: riak

I cant bring riak to work on Ubuntu 14.04. LTS using the bash instructions under
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/debian-ubuntu/.

When running riak start I get:

```
riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
```

When running riak console afterwards:

```
Exec:  /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/2.1.3/riak               -config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2016.02.28.21.43.04.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2016.02.28.21.43.04.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2016.02.28.21.43.04.args              -pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches -- console -x
Root: /usr/lib/riak
Erlang R16B02_basho8 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]

[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@127.0.0.1',[{'riak@54.194.69.48',[{{riak_core,bucket_types},[true,false]},{{riak_core,fold_req_version},[v2,v1]},{{riak_core,net_ticktime},[true,false]},{{riak_core,resizable_ring},[true,false]},{{riak_core,security},[true,false]},{{riak_core,staged_joins},[true,false]},{{riak_core,vnode_routing},[proxy,legacy]},{{riak_pipe,trace_format},[ordsets,sets]}]}]],[{file,\"orddict.erl\"},{line,72}]},{riak_core_capability,renegotiate_capabilities,1,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,441}]},{riak_core_capability,handle_call,3,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,213}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,585}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]},{gen_server,call,[riak_core_capability,{register,{riak_core,vnode_routing},{capability,[proxy,legacy],legacy,{riak_core,legacy_vnode_routing,[{true,legacy},{false,proxy}]}}},infinity]}}}}}}"}
```

Any idea how to fix this? Installation has been done via apt-get. Default riak.conf. Riak version is 2.1.3.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming? Why not try the ubuntu Q/A's?

Comment: Sorry its been pretty late yesterday - forgot to put riak in the headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Riak error, not at all related to Ubuntu.

The error message indicates that the current name of the node does not match the name of any node in the ring file.  This can happen if you start the node with a default configuration before configuring the node's name.  See `Note on changing the name value` at http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/basic-cluster-setup/

If this is a singleton node, the simplest solution will be to delete the files in `/var/lib/riak/ring` (make a backup first).  A new one will be created when you start the node.

Comment: solved it. Another problem in EC2 was that it was give an eaddressavail error when using the public IP in the name config. Using the private IP works.